# Why HTTP/2 is not supported by Android's HttpUrlConnection?

Tags: android, networking, httpurlconnection, okhttp, http2

I just found out that Android's recommended http client `HttpUrlConnection` doesn't support HTTP/2.

Is there a specific reason not to use HTTP/2 on Android?

Comment: It supported SPDY years ago, which was the precursor to HTTP/2. How are you determining that HTTP/2 is not supported? OkHttp is the better choice, for lots of reasons, though.

Comment: I am monitoring the https requests on the server side. The requests coming from the Android app using HttpUrlConnection are always HTTP/1.1, even on Android 9. While from the iOS app they are always HTTP/2.

Answer (score 8):

You can use OkHttp if you want to take advantage of HTTP/2:

https://github.com/square/okhttp

It's superior to HttpUrlConnection anyway.  If you're doing anything at all complicated, like getting complex JSON responses from a web API, I'd recommend Retrofit:

https://square.github.io/retrofit/