# Is okHttp part of Android or not?

Tags: android, okhttp

According to some references, e.g.
[Does Android use OkHttp internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000027/does-android-use-okhttp-internally)
Android is using (or at least was using) okHttp internally under HttpUrlConnection.
Still in some recent discussions (e.g. [Why HTTP/2 is not supported by Android's HttpUrlConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671739/why-http-2-is-not-supported-by-androids-httpurlconnection)) it is recommended to use okHttp from GitHub rather than Android http APIs.
So I am confused. Does anyone have a definitive answer?

Comment: why don't you just check the Android sources to be sure?

Comment: If you bundle OkHttp with your app you're in charge of the version and included bugfixes. You're in charge of allowed protocols. Is HttpsUrlConnection good enough for your use case? Then use it, save a few kb off your APK. Is OkHttp part of Android? Yes. Should you rely on it? Depends on your use case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Android 4.4 onwards using OkHttp for its internal `HttpUrlConnection` implementation

Source: https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/482563299511250944

Versions of OkHttp used in Android:

- Android 4.4: OkHttp 1.1.2
- Android 5.x: OkHttp 2.0.0
- Android 6.0: OkHttp 2.4.0
- Android 7.x: OkHttp 2.6.0
- Android 8.0+: OkHttp 2.7.5

You can check what version of OkHttp Kitkat uses here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/refs/heads/kitkat-release/pom.xml

For other Android releases replace `kitkat-release` in the URL with `<your-dessert>-release`.

Comment: Important to note: although OkHttp is used inside of AOSP, you can't access OkHttp features like interceptors. If you want that you need to include OkHttp as a library.